# Flutter: flexible row of columns

Tags: flutter, layout, aspect-ratio

I have a widget structure like this:

```
Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ...
          Stack(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 1.0,
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    ...
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

This structure placed into a Row widget N times, and Row placed inside a Column of Flexibles, a-ka:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Flexible(flex: 3, fit: FlexFit.tight, child: Row(children: [MyWidget(),MyWidget(),...]))
  ]
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsPEI.png)

Core idea is that smaller amount of items makes every item bigger, but stiil a square, and reversed, but always fits screen (vertical no scrolls).
It works almost perfectly, but in some N-s or screen width's items starts to overflow its row and parent's Flexible.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc3e6.png)

My best guess - AspectRation widget breaks layout.
I don't want to use any hardcoded box constraints.

How can i prevent that overflow?

I haven't tried anything, i'm stuck and don't know what to do

Comment: Can you include full sample widget from scaffold

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Shure:
1) Problem widget https://github.com/kong-of-diamonds/client/blob/master/lib/components/player.dart
2) Where it builds https://github.com/kong-of-diamonds/client/blob/master/lib/views/game_view.dart#L128